# Which data sources are 'workingWith' and 'trendingAround' based on?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

Which data sources are the API calls 'working with' and 'trending around' are drawing on to determine how co-workers or files are connected?

Is it just SharePoint or is it also OneNote? Can I assume that Exchange is excluded? What about Yammer?

The only place I can find a description of these calls is https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_workingwith.

Is there anywhere I can find a more detailed description?

Answer (score 0):

Working with is a people to people relationship, and trending around is a people to document relationship. They are both calculated based on public and private information. The public information includes people followings in SharePoint, organizational structure, distribution list peers, group memberships, and so forth. And private or cached information includes the recipient cache from Exchange, co-authors of SharePoint documents (including OneNote), elevated peers (people that you have looked at and clicked on their info or boards in Delve). All of these relationships feed a ranking and relevance models that calculate the people you are working with and the documents trending around you.
It does not include Yammer at this point in time.